# Default resource handler for an URL path serving a static file in Spring Boot MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I have a Spring Boot-based project (based on `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-web` in which I want to both serve static content (built in another module, and copied into the project with `maven-resources-plugin`).

With the default configuration/conventions, it looks for static content in misc. places, like `classpath:/static` and `classpath:/public`, which is useful if the static content is to be served from the root URL, which for this project is not the case.

I want to serve it off `/web/` which I have successfully done by deriving from `WebMvcConfigurer` (and annotated the class with `@Configuration`) and overridden the `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method; `registry.addResourceHandler("/web/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/web/");`

This works when explicitly referring to the file names in the `/web/`-folder, but I can't figure out how I can emulate the "default document" behavior, e.g. `index.html` should be served for `/web/`. If you drop off an `index.html` in one of the root directories for static content, it will be handled by the `WelcomePageHandlerMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution; I also had to override the `addViewControllers()` to create an explicit mapping and fix the precedence:

```java
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/web/").setViewName("index.html");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```